# pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 172.18.0.3:5672 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect a Pika client with the RabbitMQ server. Both of them are on different docker images and they are on the same docker network.
I set up my network as

```
docker network create my_first_net
```

I am running the RabbitMQ image `rabbitmq` as

```
docker run -d --network my_first_net --hostname rabbitmqhost  -p 35672:15672 -p 45672:5672 rabbitmq
```

I am running the Pika image `ms2-1` as

```
docker run --network my_first_net --hostname rabbitmq ms2-1
```

Here is the code for pika-client `ms2.py`:

```
import pika

exchange = 'gateway_exchange'

myName = 'microservice2'

myKey = '#.ms2.#'
gwKey = 'gw'

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbitmq', 5672, '/', credentials)

def send(key, message):
    send_conn = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    send_ch = send_conn.channel()

    send_ch.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange,
                             exchange_type='topic')

    send_ch.basic_publish(exchange=exchange,
                          routing_key=key,
                          body=message)
    print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % (key, message))
    send_conn.close()

def receive():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=exchange,
                             exchange_type='topic')

    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue

    binding_key = myKey
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=exchange,
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=binding_key)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))
        send('Response-from-' + myName + '-to-.' + gwKey, body)

    channel.basic_consume(callback,
                          queue=queue_name,
                          no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    receive()
```

I get the following error when I try to run the pika image

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ms2.py", line 61, in <module>
    receive()
  File "ms2.py", line 36, in receive
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 414, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 468, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed(maybe_exception)
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: Connection to 172.18.0.3:5672 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The ip address of the RabbitMQ container is `172.18.0.2` when I do `docker inspect` and it is `68.50.13.82` when I do `curl ifconfig.me` inside the container. 
I confirmed that the container is listening to port 5672 using `netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"

I think Errno 111 is related to authentication error, but I am unable to connect to either of the IP addresses from my machine.

What should be my next steps to resolve this issue?

Edit: I realized that I did not add a `--name` flag while running the RabbitMQ server, so I deleted that container and started a new one as:

```
docker run -d --network my_first_net --hostname rabbitmqhost --name rabbitmq -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq
```

But now I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ms2.py", line 61, in <module>
    receive()
  File "ms2.py", line 36, in receive
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 414, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 466, in _flush_output
    raise maybe_exception
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is happening because you are re-using the same host name while running the pika container

```
docker run --network my_first_net --hostname rabbitmq ms2-1
```

You should not set the same hostname as your rabbitmq container name. I ran same steps and I was able to connect

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
By adjusting the parameter "**socket_timeout**" I was able to get rid of the problem. The parameter description is [here](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/parameters.html#pika.connection.ConnectionParameters.socket_timeout)

Here is the code snippet,which sets socket_timeout to 15 seconds:

connection=pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='xx.xx.xx.xx',socket_timeout=15,credentials=credentials))

xx.xx.xx.xx : place your host IP.